# Best Screen capture tools to prepare presentation video

Tags: video

I would like to prepare one video presentation to explain my web product to client, can anyone please
suggest me the best tools to do this task??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked around in my social/professional circle a while ago about this, and the consensus was around two products:  [Screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/) and [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/).

Incidentally, I don't think that this question is an appropriate question for StackOverflow but hopefully this will be migrated to a different StackExchange site and this answer preserved.

Comment: Sorry for posting this question here..

Comment: No big deal.  It will just get closed or migrated if enough people vote to close/migrate it.